# Buffered Audio For Generating Sounds

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have an oscillator to generate the frequencies of a keyboard. It all works when I output to speakers, but as well as outputting to speakers I would like to buffer it so that I can turn it into base 64 and use again later. The only examples of this I have seen use xhr which I do not need as obviously I want to be able to just add a node into the modular routing to take input, store it in an array, then output to the hardware.

Something like this:

```
var osc = ctx.createOscillator();
osc.type = 3;
osc.frequency.value = freq;
osc.connect(buffer);
buffer.connect(ctx.destination);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using Matt's Recorder.js https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs and connecting it to a GainNode which acts as an intermediary from a number of oscillators to the ctx.destination. I will be using localStorage but here is an example using an array (this does not include the oscillator setup).

```
var recorder;
recorder = new Recorder(gainNode, { workerPath: "../recorderWorker.js"});
recorder.record();

var recordedSound = [];
function recordSound()  {
    recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
        recordedSound.push(blob);
    });
}

function play(i)  {
    var audio = new Audio(window.URL.createObjectURL(recordedSound[i]));
    audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered utilizing a ScriptProcessorNode?

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#ScriptProcessorNode

You would attach an eventListener to this node, allowing you to capture arrays of audio samples as they pass through. You could then save these buffers and manipulate them as you wish.

Comment: I have been looking into using that, so far only getting arrays of 0 which is odd. But I think it might be the way to go.

Comment: Do you have any code samples you could share in a jsFiddle or something?

Comment: I just threw together this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xpAEn/ .. having another error with audioBuffer though but it shows the basics of what I am trying to do.

Comment: In that example, I expect audioBuffer to include an array of frequencies that I can then go through and play again later.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out RecorderJs?  https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs.  I think it does what you need.

Comment: I did look at it but it is for microphone recording so cannot hook into the modular routing of web audio api.

Comment: Actually, I'm the creator of RecorderJS, and it can connect to the output of any Web Audio API node.

Comment: Oh can it? Will give that a try then, because I have not yet had any luck! Thanks.

Comment: This worked, thanks very much. Have posted my own answer to detail it better.